# Create a UIImageView that will iterate through an array of images

Tags: ios, swift, loops, uiimageview, swift4

I want to create a UIImageView that will iterate through an array of images.

And I want it to go faster, and faster over time — without stopping — until the user presses a button.

I've just completed a module on a Swift and Xcode course where we created an app that shows random dice faces when you press the button "roll."

I want to try do it the other way around where the images keep iterating faster and faster until the user presses a stop button.

I think the answer is below — but how do you make it go faster, and faster?

```
func animate_images()
{
    let myimgArr = ["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg"]
    var images = [UIImage]()

    for i in 0..<myimgArr.count
    {
        images.append(UIImage(named: myimgArr[i])!)
    }

    imgView_ref.animationImages = images
    imgView_ref.animationDuration = 0.04
    imgView_ref.animationRepeatCount = 2
    imgView_ref.startAnimating()
}
```

And then add this to a stop button:

```
imgView_ref.stopAnimating()
```

Or is there a simpler way to solve this challenge?

Comment: https://github.com/londonappbrewery/Auto-Layout-With-Dicee-iOS11

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with a Timer?
The Timer will allow you to execute a method. In this method, you can update a timeInterval value that will update the imageView.animationDuration value.

See below an example:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imgView_ref: UIImageView!

    var timer: Timer?
    var timeInterval = 1.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Your code
        let myimgArr = ["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg"]
        var images = [UIImage]()

        for i in 0..<myimgArr.count
        {
            images.append(UIImage(named: myimgArr[i])!)
        }

        imgView_ref.animationImages = images

        // You need to replace this line
        // imgView_ref.animationDuration = 0.04
        // with
        imgView_ref.animationDuration = timeInterval

        // Remove this line
        // imgView_ref.animationRepeatCount = 2

        imgView_ref.startAnimating()

        // Setup the timer
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    // This method will be called by the timer each timeInterval
    @objc func updateTime() {
        // Just to be sure to have a positive timeInterval
        if timeInterval > 0.05 {
            // We remove 0.05 to the previous timeInterval
            timeInterval = timeInterval - 0.05

            // We update the imgView_ref
            imgView_ref.animationDuration = timeInterval
            imgView_ref.startAnimating()

            // We update the timer in order to call this method with the new timeInterval
            timer?.invalidate()
            timer = nil
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Regards.

Comment: Perfect! And thats for the comments too! Cheer mate!